# importing source code of Jbox2d into my maven repository to be used as a dependancy

Tags: maven, jbox2d

I have downloaded the source of Jbox2d using:
svn checkout http://jbox2d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ jbox2d-read-only

How do I import the source code of Jbox2d into my maven repository to be used as a dependancy? Thanks

Comment: Why would you like to import the source code into a maven repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build the source code into an artifact (jar file) and deploy that jar file incl. a created pom to the maven repository.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DartifactId=x.y.z -DgroupId=a.b.c -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile=xyz.jar -Durl=http://URL/TO/MAVEN/REPOSITOY ...
```